# A Diophantine equation along with an inequality

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all positive integers $a, b, c$ and integers $x, y, z$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
ax^2+by^2+cz^2=abc+2xyz-1\\
ab+bc+ca\geq x^2+y^2+z^2
\end{align*}$$

My Progress - By $\pmod 4$. I could conclude that at least one of the $a, b, c$ has to be even to satisfy the parity of both sides.

Comment: I don't believe that at least one of the $a,b,c$ has to be even. Take $a=b=c=1$ and $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: This seems like a rather difficult problem. Is this some sort of AoPS question?

Answer (score 0):

In this equation:

$$aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2=abc+2XYZ+F$$

$F$ - integer number given by the condition of the problem.
A rather Tran decision:

$$a=(2pk-p^2+p-k^2)((t-s)^2-1)+2tsk+p(1-t^2)-(2k-p+1)s^2+F$$

$$b=(2pk-p^2+p-k^2)((t-s)^2-1)+2tsk-pt^2-(2k-p+1)(s^2-1)+F$$

$$c=(t-s)^2-1$$

$$X=t$$

$$Y=s$$

$$Z=(2pk-p^2+p-k^2)((t-s)^2-1)+k(2ts+1)-pt^2-(2k-p+1)s^2+F$$

$p,s,k,t$ - integers asked us.

Comment: Thanks for copy-pasting these answers but I have already seen it on that AoPS blog after using the search fxn. Could you please share your working? Also, I think there is an inequality given which may (or may not) affect the answer.